# (Mail Delivery Subsystem) check if the receiver email is able to receive or not?

Tags: gmail, email-delivery

I'm trying to send important email to an organization. their email account is always full. thus, It never receives my email due to the following error.

title:
Mail Delivery Subsystem

from:
mailer-daemon@googlemail.com

message:
Your message could not be delivered to ******@gmail.com. Either his inbox is full or he's getting a lot of mail right now.

The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct the recipient to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaTemp

[not exact but similar problem](https://support.google.com/mail/search?q=Mail%20Delivery%20Subsystem&from_promoted_search=true)

The error is clear but I need to find some solution.

**I need some service or app to check out if the target email "the receiver" is available to receive now or not.**

I assume the receiver might empty some space someday, and then I can send my email again if I have  sort of service like the up mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Internet standard, this is an expected behaviour and there is no work around for this unless the organization is willing to let you access the API for their account, which won't likely be the scenario since it is like asking to share access to their Gmail account to check the content.

If you had the notification **Message sent**(*which appears at the bottom left after sending your email*) and you do not receive the **Message not delivered** email and it is safe to assume that your message has been delivered to their inbox.

What you can do on top of this is to enable the read receipt when you compose your message. This is the closest thing we can have of getting a notification from the recipient.
[image]

The way read receipt works is when they open your email they will have a prompt to notify you with the option to approve or not. If they approve it you will receive an email notification, otherwise, you won't.

- Read receipt reference Link: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308953?hl=en

Comment: thank you it's the same conclusion as I guessed. however, you give me great idea in the beginning of your answer. I can make google app script application to give some service which is important to the organization itself something like sorting files based on criteria or prevent repetition registration or  filtering files based on some key words intensity ...ect  >>> if I can convince them to use my app that might allow me to get some info such as the one I need `when they have space` or even more via google permission. do you think this idea might work ?

Comment: You can make use of the insert in your script and try a random blob file. This will check whether there is enough space before sending email: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert.

Or the storageQuota method. This will return the drive's used space in bytes however this would require a more complex form of authentication (domain wide) level or per-user level.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about