# Email tracking pixel tracking email opened even when sender is clicking on the email

Tags: email, smtp, gmail-api, pixel

I am building an email application using gmail api to send an email [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) to track if the receiver has opened email I am adding 1x1pixel in the email html body. I want to do these two things

1. When ever sender open email I dont want to count that as viewed.
2. When receiver opens the email I want to send a notification to sender that email has been opened.

Comment: This is an arms race. People are [designing software](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2022/02/01/email-tracking-privacy/) specifically to prevent this kind of unwanted intrusion on their privacy.

Comment: Good luck.  Privacy controls mean this will be increasingly impossible.  As for the tracking pixel being different between sender and receiver, this isn’t really possible with the Gmail API.  Unless you delete the email that was automatically put in the Sent folder and put a _slightly_ different copy there yourself with (IMAP APPEND or the gmail equivalent)

Comment: Re: arms race; most security conscious people don’t load images at all from senders they don’t know.  Apple’s mail clients randomize when images are fetched and will do it through a proxy to preserve privacy, etc.  I think Gmail may do the same.  You’ve already lost for probably 20+% of potential email viewers.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, both of your statements involve the read receipt function of Gmail. [Request or return a read receipt](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651)

> To find out when an email you sent was opened, you can request a read receipt. A read receipt is sent to you as an email with the time and date of when your message was opened.

Since you are using the Gmail API in order to create your email application, you may find these Stack Overflow posts useful in answering your question, as what you'd like may not be currently available:

[(Mail Delivery Subsystem) check if the receiver email is able to receive or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71520552)

[Gmail Api Mail Read Reciept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641155)

Comment: I am trying to find when did reviver opened the email when sent using gmail api above links doesn't contain any information regarding this

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it's not the answer you're looking for and that I misunderstood your post. Based on your definition, `I am trying to find when did reviver opened the email when sent using gmail api`, the Gmail API does not have the feature you're looking for, but if you'd like, you may create one using a third-party provider. If you would still like to use Gmail's API for this, you can submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) as suggested by [KENdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5996134) on their answer in the second post.

Answer (score 1):

Send two slightly different versions of the message, with the same message-id, same header fields, and same content except that

- the one you send to the sender lacks the tracking pixel
- the one you send to the recipient has a tracking pixel

Easily done using any programming language. You'll need to use an outgoing SMTP server that you control, so it won't force a cc to the sender, but you can get that for free. Postfix and Exim both act as you want in the stock configuration.

Comment: BTW. If using a tracking pixel is too boring for you, you could get the same effect by inserting something like this instead: [<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=UnifrakturCook:700"> <div style="font-family: UnifrakturCook;">](https://rant.gulbrandsen.priv.no/hack/web-fonts-email) where the link to the web font tracks the user.

Comment: `` {
  accepted: [ 'P1', 'p2' ],
  rejected: [],
  ehlo: [
    'SIZE 35882577',
    '8BITMIME',
    'AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH',
    'ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES',
    'PIPELINING',
    'CHUNKING',
    'SMTPUTF8'
  ],
  envelopeTime: 1022,
  messageTime: 835,
  messageSize: 325,
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK  1695039274 w30-20020a934pgm.62 - gsmtp',
  envelope: {
    from: 'sender@gmail.com,
    to: [ 'P1', 'P2' ]
  },
  messageId: '<f6e2-257c-45c8-XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com>'
}``
Getting only messageId in headers no other headers while sending an email

Comment: I can't even tell what you're trying to say. But I can tell you're using gmail, which is *not* an SMTP server that you control.

Comment: can you please check this question I am also trying to do something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77089925/how-to-track-read-status-for-individual-recipients-by-adding-pixel-tracking

Comment: Sure. The answer is much the same. Easy enough unless you insist on making it difficult for yourself.